# stdClass (again)

Tags: php, foreach, stdclass

think I'm going mad but think i've tried everything possible!

got an object like so;

```
    object(stdClass)#9 (8) {
  ["Results"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#10 (5) {
      ["EmailAddress"]=>
      string(22) "38ec95a@emailtests.com"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(13) "Daniel Crabbe"
      ["Date"]=>
      string(19) "2011-07-11 13:00:00"
      ["State"]=>
      string(6) "Active"
      ["CustomFields"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#11 (5) {
      ["EmailAddress"]=>
      string(12) "dan@jynk.net"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(13) "Daniel Crabbe"
      ["Date"]=>
      string(19) "2011-10-11 12:43:00"
      ["State"]=>
      string(6) "Active"
      ["CustomFields"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#12 (5) {
      ["EmailAddress"]=>
      string(23) "nikolaprice@hotmail.com"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(12) "Nicola Price"
      ["Date"]=>
      string(19) "2011-08-25 16:24:00"
      ["State"]=>
      string(6) "Active"
      ["CustomFields"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["ResultsOrderedBy"]=>
  string(5) "email"
  ["OrderDirection"]=>
  string(3) "asc"
  ["PageNumber"]=>
  int(1)
  ["PageSize"]=>
  int(150)
  ["RecordsOnThisPage"]=>
  int(3)
  ["TotalNumberOfRecords"]=>
  int(3)
  ["NumberOfPages"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

and trying to loop through array(3) and get the email addresses with;

```
foreach($subscribed_result->results as $sr){
    $res++;
    echo $res.": ".$sr->EmailAddress." ".$sr['EmailAddress']." ";
}
```

and several variations but getting nowhere. what am into understanding?

**Updates**

this works better and can get the object from $sr as an array but still can't get $sr->emailAddress.

```
print $subscribed_result->response->Results[0]->EmailAddress; // works?

        foreach($subscribed_result->response->Results as $sr){
            echo $sr->EmailAdress."";   // doesn't work? 
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($sr);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
```

spits out;

```
stdClass Object
(
    [EmailAddress] => 38ec95a@emailtests.com
    [Name] => Daniel Crabbe
    [Date] => 2011-07-11 13:00:00
    [State] => Active
    [CustomFields] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you put the var_dump of $sr here please?

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

```
foreach($subscribed_result->Results as $sr){
    $res++;
    echo $res.": ".$sr->EmailAdress;
}
```

Notice the `Results` instead of `results`. `Results` is an object, so `$sr['EmailAddress']` wont work. You can access only arrays as this. `$sr->EmailAddress` will print what you want.

To illustrate, this is how you would access the first email address directly:

```
print $subscribed_result->Results[0]->EmailAddress;
```

Comment: yeh - getting an error for that foreach; 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vhosts/modernactivity.com/httpdocs/youradmin_v2/scripts/php/cm_sendCampaign.php on line 289' and the print test doesn't work either?

Comment: You didn't think to mention the warning?

Comment: warning is new with '$subscribed_result->Results as $sr'!

Comment: Try with lower "r" as you had it before. I get the warning when I use lower "r". Might be some settings issue.